# Is $(-1)^{\infty}=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity, infinite-product

I was recently working across the [ADT Queue](https://github.com/AitzazImtiaz/ADT-Queue) when I thought that such a scenario can be defined by the Grandi series. It is [given](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5Ek+%28-1%29%5En) that:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^k (-1)^n = \frac{1}{2}\big((-1)^k + 1\big)
$$
It is seemingly visible that both are divergent series, and as $k \rightarrow \infty$ it can be said that:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n = \frac{1}{2}\big((-1)^\infty + 1\big)
$$
It can be now said that:
$$
2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n = (-1)^\infty + 1
$$
The LHS gives us the infinite series:

```
2-2+2-2+2...
```

It can now be solved on LHS, treating it as divergent series:
$$
\begin{gather}
S = 2-2+2-2+2...\\
2-S = 2-(2-2+2-2+2...)\\
2-S=S\\
S=2S\\
S=1\\
\end{gather}
$$
Continuing where we left above solving the LHS, it can be said,
$$
1 = (-1)^{\infty} + 1
$$
$$
(-1)^{\infty}=0
$$
My question is:

- Is $(-1)^{\infty}$ actually determinate?
- Is the proof I wrote here correct?

Disclaimer: I am newly 16 years old elementary math student with no expertise (in formal ways) in the subject. I did not write this question simply to waste others' time. I hope the question stays here, with a criticism/appreciation of the proof I presented.

Comment: This is a great question and there is no obvious reason that it should be downvoted. If the answer is trivial then it isn't so to the OP

Comment: thanks for the support sir, mind asking me what is the full form of OP? I made this account a year ago but am planning to stay active here recently. thanks! :)

Comment: An OP means "original post". This is what you are asking for, right?

Comment: ja sir, thanks so much! merci! :)

Comment: Grandi's series does not converge in ordinary sense. It converges in Cesàro sense, which means that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_1+S_2+\cdots+S_n}{n}=\frac{1}{2}\qquad\text{where}\quad S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}.$$ This then translates to the fact that the **Cesàro mean** of $(-1)^n$ is $0$: $$C(1)\text{-}\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n :=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k}{n}=0. $$ Here, you can think of Cesàro mean as a generalized limit, because the Abel's theorem tells that every sequence that has limit in $[-\infty,\infty]$ in ordinary sense also has the Cesàro mean with the same value.

Comment: Your second formula is a problem. You can't simply replace the meaningful and finite symbol k with the meaningless symbol $\infty$ and pretend that they share a meaning. The infinite sum has to mean something, it must have a value if you want it to equal something else. What is that value?

Comment: The word *conjecture* is used for a statement which is believed to be true but has not been proved. The identity you quoted from WolframAlpha  is a fact, not a conjecture. I edited this one word from your post to avoid confusion.

Comment: thanks, ugh, I thought it is a conjecture simply because WolframAlpha did not show the proof and I could not use the pro version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have proven:

> If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$ converges, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n = 0$.

There is a quicker way to get there: The terms in *any* convergent series must tend to zero as a sequence.

While the conditional statement is true, its hypothesis is not satisfied: Grandi's series does not converge. So no conclusion can be drawn from the statement.

Comment: Great answer! Are you hiding the Riemann series theorem behind it? As I want to add this in my answer and I want to make sure I am not repeating what you put.

Comment: @KamalSaleh In the courses I teach in the US, we sometimes call it the "$n$th term test." I don't know a fancier name for it. The proof is: Suppose a series converges. Then its partial sums converge as a sequence. This means the difference between consecutive partial sums converges to zero. But that difference is nothing more than the $n$th term.

Comment: @KamalSaleh I believe the theorem you are referring to is about rearrangements, and you are correct that Grandi's series can be rearranged in a way which is "more obviously" divergent.

Comment: Yes I am referring to rearrangements. So if I put this in my answer, I won't be copying yours right? Also thanks for the new info (I am a self-learner so I don't know some of the terms used at school).

Comment: @KamalSaleh no I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot be said.

The limit of $(-1)^n$ as $n\to \infty$ doesn't exist.

First you should learn calculus, math sorcerer in YT recommends a lot of calculus books. Pick one...

Comment: Thanks sir, I am thankful for your suggestion, right now I am not even studying pre-calculus as of my elementary school course :)

Answer (score 0):

$(-1)^x$ is usually not defined for non integer $x$. So here stating that $(-1)^\infty$ exists is like saying that $\infty$ is an integer. This is not true, as $\infty$ is not a real or complex number. Another argument we could make is that you have "rearranged" the terms in your sum. This changes its value according to Riemann's rearrangement theorem, which states that shuffling the terms of a convergent sum could change its value.